# Where do I store data which is loaded on each request, in a Bottle-powered app?

Tags: python, bottle

I have a simple Bottle app which stores its configuration in a text file. Naturally, I need the config to be available in almost every handler of the app, and I want it to be reloaded on every request.

In Flask I could load the config file into a `ConfigParser` instance in `before_request` and put a reference to it into an attribute of the `g` object, just as described in the Flask documentation as a way of [connecting SQLite](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlite3/). The `g` object would then be available in every handler:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.config = load_config()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    param = g.config.get(...)
    ...
```

In Bottle, on the other hand, thread locals are considered a bad thing, and the suggested way of storing the DB connection is [to write a plugin](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.9/plugindev.html#plugin-example-sqliteplugin) which analyzes the handlers for signatures using clever tricks. And while the problem is already solved for SQLite, it is not in case of some other arbitrary per-request data.

To be frank, I can't believe I'm supposed to write 60 lines of code to do such a simple task, so I guess I must be missing something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want it reloaded every single request, why not just use a function?

```
def get_config():
    with open('config.json') as f:
        return json.load(f)

@route('/')
def index():
    config = get_config()
    return 'Welcome to %s' % config['site_name']
```

If you wanted to wrap that into a plugin it's fairly simple:

```
def config_plugin(callback):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['config'] = get_config()
        return callback(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

install(config_plugin)

@route('/')
def index(config):
    return 'Welcome to %s' % config['site_name']
```

Comment: Thanks. Config was a model example though. Suppose I have three or four similar things I need to track within a request. Of course, few of handlers need all of them, most only require one or two, and some, like static file handlers, need no at all. On the other hand, your solution implies _every_ handler accepts a `config` argument. I suppose I can adapt the “60-line plugin”, but that’s what I wanted to avoid: this seems like on overkill, as simple problems (e.g. loading config) want simple solutions.

Comment: @Helgi Nah not at all. You should read the plugin documentation it's more flexible than that. You aren't forced to apply the plugin to every route: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#route-specific-installation. Not really sure what you want, but you might want to read up on thread locals in python too: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.local.